# Mixed-effect modeling with paired observations & bounded response variables

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

I am quite new in the field of mixed-effect modeling. For a beginner like me, I guess I combine several levels of complication in my analysis: paired observations & bounded response variables. I hope to be clear in my description and to get some useful comments, at least on some of the challenges I face. Thanks in advance.

In a nutshell, my objective is to compare performance of several species distribution model types based on several performance indexes, across a set of 89 species.

**Responses variables:** AUC metric (bounded between 0 and 1) or Boyce index (bounded between -1 and 1)

**Fixed effect:** model_type (climatic_model, land_use_model)

**Random effect:** 89 species, 10 replicates for each of the 89 species

I guess one could do:

`fit1<-lme(model_performance_value~model_type, random=~1|species, data=dat)`

Using summary(fit1), I get:

```
Fixed effects: model_performance_value ~ model_type 
                        Value   Std.Error   DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept)             0.6362836 0.028055699 1690 22.67930       0
techniqueunbiased_boyce 0.1680262 0.007156959 1690 23.47732       0
```

(1) Is it fine to get the 0 p-values (became <0.001 using aov(fit1))?

(2) Do you think the DFs are ok?

(3) If I use the AUC as response variable it is limited to [0,1] and if I use the Boyce index, it is restricted to [-1,1]. Should I use other models with such response variables?

**CONSIDERING PAIRED COMPARISONS:**
The response variable of species A replicate 1 climatic_model is paired with the response variable of species A replicate 1 land_use_model. The replicates are paired between model types but within a given species. I made another variable called paired_id. This variable was written as "species"_"replicate", and takes 10 replicates x 89 species=890 values.

```
model_type species replicate paired_id
clim          A        1         A_1
land          A        1         A_1
clim          A        2         A_2
land          A        2         A_2
clim          B        1         B_1
```

Following this link (example in a much easier context) http://www2.compute.dtu.dk/~hmad/GLM/Slides_2012/week09/lect09.pdf, I did:

```
fit1<-lme(model_performance_value~model_type, random=~1|species/paired_id, data=subset)
```

I obtained a 0 p-value, and a DF=890. I am not sure it works this way, at all, though. I guess it is more complicated than this.

Has anyone some tips for me? Any help much appreciated!