# Bounded response variable [-1;1] - Should I transform it?

Tags: r, distributions, mixed-model, data-transformation, bounds

I am planning to use two response variables. One is bounded between 0 and 1, and I guess I can use a binomial (or related) error structure. The second variable is bounded between -1 and 1. I am not sure what should I do for this one. Should I transform it? Please note that I plan to use these variables in mixed-effect modeling (see related post on mixed-effect modeling: [Mixed-effect modeling with paired observations & bounded response variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57349/mixed-effect-modeling-with-paired-observations-bounded-response-variables)). Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: If it's not a count, I wouldn't say 'binomial'. You *might* say 'beta'. (Similarly, the second might be a recaled beta.); you can of course transform either to the real line also.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. None of the two variables are counts. The first is a proportion. The second is actually a correlation coefficient, thus ranging from -1 to 1 (the purpose of the analysis is to compare model performance indexes across different types of species distribution models).

Comment: However, as far as I know, the lme4 package does not allow to model the logit of the mean of a beta distribution... Any tips for data transformation? Thanks a lot

Comment: The obvious transformation to the real line for something on [0,1] is any continuous inverse-cdf, the logit transform being a canonical example; though you will likely be left with heteroscedasticity. For something on $[-1,1]$ you can add 1 and divide by 2 to get something on $[0,1]$ and apply the same idea; if you then use logits, that's the same as $\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ on the original correlation. The [variance-stabilizing transform for the correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation) *turns out to be the same thing* (aside from a multiple of 1/2).   I'd try that first.

Comment: Though if you have any exact 0's or 1's in the first variable or exact -1's or 1's in the second variable, these won't work as-is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made a few trials, and indeed I am left with heteroscedasticity... The Logit transformation did not help much, do you think there is anything fundamentally wrong to treat it as it is if I fulfilled the normality & variance equality assumptions? The Fisher transformation did a good job with the second response variable though. Overall, the variances may be too unequal to be used in lme(). Any idea what could I use as alternative technique (sorry if asking too much).

Comment: Unmodelled heterosckedasticity will be [a problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity#Consequences) when you're trying to calculate standard errors of coefficients (and so also when trying to test significance of predictors, construct confidence intervals). There are other things I might consider (such as trying to make the variance more stable and then worrying about modelling the mean in a more complicated way)